# Some problems appear when i use Macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
data classivar_1;
set classvar;
AnaClassVar=scan(scan(F2,1," "),2,".");
run;
proc sql;
select AnaClassVar into : MacClassVar separated by "#" from classivar_1 ;
select count(*) into: Count_classvar from classivar_1;
quit;
%put &MacClassVar.;
%put &Count_classvar.;
ods output variables=adsl_var;
proc contents data=ev.adsl;
run;
proc sql;
select variable into : AllVar separated by "#" 
from adsl_var;
select count(*)  into : Count_Allvar from adsl_var;
quit;
%put &Allvar.;
%put &Count_Allvar.;

**** set up Macro ClassAna to analyze the classified varialbes;

%macro ClassAna(datasets= );
%do i= 1 %to &Count_classvar.;
%do count=1 %to &Count_Allvar;
%if %sysfunc(find(%scan(&MacClassVar,&i,#),%scan(&AllVar,&count,#)))
%then %do;
%let Class_var&i.=%scan(&AllVar,&count,#);
%end;
%end;
%put &&Class_var&i..;
%end;
%Mend;
%ClassAna(datasets=sashelp.class)
```

When I submit the programme , the macro variable Class_var6 cannot be resolved.
But other macro variables can be resolved correctly.
The logs are in the picture.enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47TQL.jpg)

Comment: can you show error in log.... use `option mprint mlogic symbolgen` at the top of your code

Answer (score 2):

In %ClassAna you are conditionally creating the macro vars based on:

```
%if %sysfunc(find(%scan(&MacClassVar,&i,#),%scan(&AllVar,&count,#)))
%then %do;
```

That FIND is case sensitive by default. I think it will work if you make it case insensitive by adding the optional i parameter to FIND. Something like:

```
%if %sysfunc(find(%scan(&MacClassVar,&i,#),%scan(&AllVar,&count,#),i))
%then %do;
```

Or you could %upcase both variable lists and leave the FIND as is.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is perfect.